# Rebar3 installation fail

Tags: erlang, ubuntu-16.04, pango, rebar3, linuxbrew

I am trying to install `rebar3` using `linuxbrew` on Ubuntu 16.04.

After I execute `brew install rebar3`

> distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc-5' failed with exit status
>   1
>   /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gobject-introspection/1.56.0/share/gobject-introspection-1.0/Makefile.introspection:159:
>   recipe for target 'Pango-1.0.gir' failed

This error occurs when trying to install **pango** dependency.

My `$PATH` has `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin` in it.

After I get this error, I manually installed `pango` using `sudo apt-get install libghc-pango-dev`

GCC version - 5.4.0

Kernel - 4.13.0-37

But still I get the same error again and again.

Answer (score 1):

libghc means it's a binding for haskell.

I believe you need libpango1.0-dev

Answer (score 1):

`rebar3` is just one file. Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/getting-started#section-installing-binary) on how to install it.

Linuxbrew doesn't work quite as well as Homebrew (in macOS), so for a lot of packages you will find out losing more time trying to make it work than just using alternatives.

In any case, if you choose that route it will be something like (1) downloading the `rebar3` binary, (2) making it executable and (3) putting it somewhere that's available anywhere — in your user's `PATH`.

---

Another approach would be to use [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/): `nix-env --install --prebuilt-only rebar3` — way easier although the introduction to it takes more time.

Comment: Yes, I tried to install rebar3 alone, but it didn't work either. `/home/sachith/rebar3/_build/default/lib/erlware_commons/src/ec_dictionary.erl:none: no such file or directory`

Comment: When I try `nix` as you suggested, **error: build of '/nix/store/wdn5dk0a4ggqj740xabdjr58gxzda397-rebar3-3.4.3.drv' failed**

Comment: `rebar3` does not bundle Erlang. You need to install it beforehand. Then you can simply do `wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rebar3/rebar3 && chmod +x rebar3` and in that same folder execute: `./rebar3 --version`...then you should get something like: `rebar 3.5.0 on Erlang/OTP 20 Erts 9.2`.